# Conditionally format number decimals after converting them to centimetres or inches

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, number-formatting, units-of-measurement

I have a toggle that converts my numbers to centimetres or inches with 1 decimal.

However, I would like centimetres to have no decimals, while inches have 1 decimal place.

This is my current code:

```
function converTo(scale) {
  $('#ct_size_guide-1761 td').each(() => {
   // I forgot exact conversion:
    var multiplier = (scale == 'in') ? 2.5 : 0.4; 
    var newVal=(parseFloat($(this).text()) * multiplier).toFixed(1);   

    $(this).text(newVal);
    $(this).siblings('.scale').text((scale=='in')? 'cm' : 'in') ;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to conditionally format the numbers, the same way you use different values for `multiplier` depending on the selected unit.

So you need to replace:

```
var multiplier = scale === 'in' ? 2.5 : 0.4;
var newVal = (parseFloat($(this).text()) * multiplier).toFixed(1);
```

With something like:

```
var newVal = scale === 'in'
  ? (parseFloat($(this).text()) * 2.5).toFixed(1)
  : (parseFloat($(this).text()) * 0.4).toFixed(0);
```

This way you can have different multipliers but also different formatting for each unit.

I would probably restructure the code with an `if-else` rather than a ternary. This way it will be easier to implement different behaviours (conversion, formatting...) depending on the selected unit:

```js
const $value = $('#value');
const $unit = $('#unit');
const $result = $('#result');

function updateConverstion() {
  const value = parseFloat($value.val());
  const unit = $unit.val();
  
  let targetValue;
  let targetUnit;
  
  if (unit === 'in') {
    // Show centimeters without decimals:
    targetValue = Math.round(value * 2.54);
    targetUnit = 'cm';
  } else {
    // Show inches with 1 decimal:
    targetValue = (value * 0.393701).toFixed(1);
    targetUnit = 'in';
  }

  $result.text(`${ value } ${ unit } = ${ targetValue } ${ targetUnit }`);
}

$value.on('input', updateConverstion);
$unit.on('change', updateConverstion);

updateConverstion();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="100" id="value" />

<select id="unit">
  <option value="cm" selected>Centimeters</option>
  <option value="in">Inches</option>
</select>

<p id="result"></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't work, and now my inches have alot of decimals

Comment: I see ur example however the one u provided for my specific case doesn't work, you have any idea why?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? It's a runnable snippet. If you enter some value and select the unit, it will convert it to the other unit. Isn't that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Your snippet works, however what u said i should replace didn't make it work, so idk how to fix that :)

Comment: I have also updated the code you are referring to. You just need to round or call `.toFixed()` in both cases, but with different values depending on how many decimals you want to show for each unit.